# Kendo Grid set the aggregate based on selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

By default my grid already had the total price (if none is selected).
What I wanted if the row/checkbox is selected, the "Total Price" only calculate the sum based on selected row. Need help how can I achieve this.

[Here is my Kendo Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/UKeTOCul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a placeholder element in the footer and update the content based on the selection:

```
function onChange(arg) {
      var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
      var data =[];
      grid.selectedKeyNames().forEach((itm)=>{
        data.push(grid.dataSource.get(itm));
      });
      var totalSelectedAmount = data.map(x=>x.UnitPrice).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      $("#total").html(totalSelectedAmount)
    }
```

[Example](https://dojo.telerik.com/ijUJiCAv)